# PHP spam issues with Gmail and Hotmail

Tags: php, gmail, hotmail, email-spam

I'm having some crazy spam problems with the following code in gMail and Hotmail.. is there something I'm doing wrong from a PHP perspective?

```
function mail_attachment($filename, $path, $mailto, $from_mail, $from_name, $replyto, $subject, $message) {
$file = $path.$filename;
$file_size = filesize($file);
$handle = fopen($file, "r");
$content = fread($handle, $file_size);
fclose($handle);
$content = chunk_split(base64_encode($content));
$uid = md5(uniqid(time()));
$name = basename($file);
$header = "From: ".$from_name." <".$from_mail.">\r\n";
$header .= "Reply-To: ".$replyto."\r\n";
$header .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$uid."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-type:text/plain; charset=iso-8859-1\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $message."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$filename."\"\r\n"; // use different content types here
$header .= "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\r\n";
$header .= "Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$filename."\"\r\n\r\n";
$header .= $content."\r\n\r\n";
$header .= "--".$uid."--";
if (mail($mailto, $subject, "", $header)) {
    echo "mail send ... OK"; // or use booleans here
} else {
    echo "mail send ... ERROR!";
}
} 
$my_file = "f92ffc796f.jpg";
$my_path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/resources/template/uploads/";
$my_name = "BB Avatar";
$my_mail = "someone@somehwerecom";
$my_replyto = "someone@somehwerecom";
$my_subject = "This is a mail with attachment.";
$my_message = "Hallo,\r\ndo Your download is attached.\r\n\r\";
mail_attachment($my_file, $my_path, $_REQUEST['email'], $my_mail, $my_name, $my_replyto, $my_subject, $my_message);
```

Comment: By "spam issues", what do you mean? Major email providers marking messages as spam?

Answer (score 0):

[Try using Swift Mailer with proper credentials :)](http://swiftmailer.org)

Also check out:

- [How to (legitimately) minimize being seen as spam](http://swiftmailer.org/wikidocs/v3/tips/spam)

Answer (score 0):

Spam issue because of following reasons

1)Shared hosting

If you are using shared hosting, PHP is not the solutions for this issue.try to contact your server providers.Some time your hosted IP treated as spam.Try to change the hosting providers, It may work fine.

2) More Links in your e-mail body

3 )Partial header(Always use reply-to,Ref Ans:TrentonMcManus)

4) Bulk E-Mailing

5) Spam Reporting(number of people who have clicked on your link as spam)

6) The message not to be too short or too long.

7) Sending From Blacklisted IP(hosting, and SMTP server) )

It may be new your IP address has been previously blacklisted by Google or Hotmail
You can check Blacklisted ip or not from the site from [here](http://www.robtex.com/)

8)Verifying sender IP

Sender Policy Framework (SPF) is an email validation system designed to prevent email spam by detecting email spoofing, a common vulnerability, by verifying sender IP addresses.

Perhaps PHP not solutions for this.You can do in php coding following things

1)Always use  the from/reply to address

2)Add  unsubscribe link in body

3)Avoid spam keywords.

4)The message not to be too short or too long.

5)Text version is better than HTML

Comment: thanks, server is an MT (dv) server, i've tested sending via SMTP as well (via phpMailer) and still no luck. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Which method("mail", "sendmail", or "smtp") you are using to send e-mail in PHPMailer class?

Comment: I have same problem before.Please try to send directly in your webmail account.That mail also may go to spam.try and get back with me.

Answer (score -1):

One thing I can see that is going to cause you problems is that:

```
$my_mail = "someone@somehwerecom";
$my_replyto = "someone@somehwerecom";
```

Should be:

```
$my_mail = "someone@somehwere.com";
$my_replyto = "someone@somehwere.com";
```

If you are sending lots of email from this script, you may be marked as SPAM if you are not complying with the [CAN SPAM Act](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAN-SPAM_Act_of_2003). It may have nothing to do with your php.

I haven't used them, but I talked to some guys from [Send Grid](http://sendgrid.com/), who claimed that their service can help ensure that the email gets delivered properly.

Comment: thanks, but that's just a typo, I replaced the actual email addresses with fake ones.

Comment: Maybe I'm blind, but these two sets of variables look identical to me.